# How to permanently resolve the permission problems on Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2

Good Morning,
i realized that for some time I have problems with permissions Apache. Let me explain, I created a file upload ajax, when transferring the uploaded file to the folder "files" hangs around, I tried the same script (copy-paste, I have not even touched the link) on a website and there everything works. Surely this is permission problems, how do I solve these problems once and for all permit? I use Apache on Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you can share some of the code so we can see what's occurring and help you out?

Comment: Question is not quite clear. What is your steps and where is the problem?

Comment: SE Linux can prevent Apache from launching off processes that edit file.

Comment: The problem I think it's in the permits. I wanted to know how to change the permissions to run the upload.

Comment: please provide more info as earlier advised. have you tried using chmod to change the permissions to the folder? usually there is an associated www user (but a quick test is to set it to 777 - full access - to see if that's really it, but don't forget to turn it back!)

Comment: Yes I was right is a permission problem, with 777 works. Thank you so much, Can I leave it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using 'chmod' to change the permissions to the folder?

Usually there is an associated www user for which you can set the permissions to be able to have write and read access to the folder, not just read.

More info on the command [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm).

A way to test for the permissions is to set to full access, i.e. `"chmod -R 777 ."` if you are in the current directory.

*Remember not to leave it on 777 as it's accessible by everyone.*